# Close a tab in Lightning Console in a visualforce page

Tags: lightning-console

I am trying to have console app work in both SFDC Classic and Lightning. I'm trying to close a sub tab via some JavaScript code. With Classic Console I did the following:

```
sforce.console.closeTab(id, callback);
```

The above method written in JS is invoked from `apex:commandbutton` with `oncomplete` attribute.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_classic_bridge_methods.htm) provided in Console Developer guide, `closeTab()` and `getEnclosingTabId()` methods are supported in both Classic and Lightning and no additional considerations are required to make the methods work in Lightning. But I see that the `closeTab()` functionality is not working as expected when accessed in Lightning experience.

I see there are some equivalent method which are supported only in Lightning Console [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_closeTab.htm).

But this is called from within a Lightning component. How can I do that from a VisualForce page?

Answer (score -1):

```
var callCloseTab= function callCloseTab(result) {
    sforce.console.closeTab(result.id);
}

function closeTab() {
    sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(callCloseTab);
}

closeTab();
</script>
```

Comment: Code dumps tend to be poor answers because they don't explain _what_ the problem is, _how_ to fix it, and _why_ the fix works. This usually leads to a chain of comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" that make it harder for other people with similar questions to follow.